# Passing information from one service to another in WSO2 ESB

Tags: header, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a requirement where I need to pass some values from one service to another.For example:we can pass values in RHF2Headers in WMB.I am trying to find out a way in WSO2 to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to pass? As HTTP headers? Query param? Or inside body?

Comment: Hi Bee - I want to pass the headers inside the Body.

Comment: what do you mean by headers inside the body? are you not talking about http headers?